# Credit Memo Email

Tags: magento-1.7

How do I edit the "Grand Total" in the credit memo email to "Refund Amount". I don't see Grand Total in the transactional email template for credit memo.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Comment: No, I actually gave up and forgot about it. Too busy. I have to try again.

Answer (score 1):

Certain blocks are included via a reference in the email. To find out where the HTML actually comes from check the layout XMLs, in case of the credit memo email that would be the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml`

Among others you'll find the handle `sales_email_order_creditmemo_items` which is the one you're looking for. You'll see that it has a block called `creditmemo_totals` that uses a template `sales/order/totals.phtml`

Now the issue is that the template is used in a bunch of places so editing it directly will result in those changes showing up basically everywhere in the store and emails.

You can set another template for this block by adding it in either a custom modules layout XML or in your active templates `local.xml` or other layout XML. That would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>
      <reference name="creditmemo_totals">
         <action method="setTemplate"><file>your/custom/sales/order/totals.phtml</file></action>
      </reference>
   </sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>
</layout>
```

Now copy the `totals.phtml` template file to your custom version and you're done

Comment: I do not see "Grand Total" in the totals.phtml

Comment: @Sander Mangel: Your answer doesn't helps to solve this comlpetely!